# Is it possible to call an AlertDialog from my Application in Android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a service that is monitoring a state and when a specific state is encountered I need to notify the user (regardless of which Activity they're in, or for that matter if they're even using the application).

Currently I'm sending a Toast from my Application (which quite oddly only works some of the time on the xoom (haven't tested on other devices).  However, when I try to launch an AlertDialog from within the Application, the app crashes.

So... Alarm wakes up and calls pending intent which launches Service which checks some stuff and if conditions are right calls up to Application to display notification. I know I can set up broadcast receivers in my app, but the whole point is to make the user actually click "OK" to the notification, even if they're not in the app at the moment, plus, it's a hassle to set up broadcast listeners in every Activity, since this process isn't tied to any activity in particular.

Is this an illegal maneuver? If not, what should I be looking for as the culprit of the crash? Is there some special permission I'm overlooking?

Comment: I think a broadcastreceiver is the way to go- I wouldn't think you need one in every activity - just one in a dialog themed activity that will handle the notification and present an ack button.

Comment: right... as I just said to MisterSquonk, below... I totally forgot that I can have a themed activity that I can call up out of the blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this an illegal maneuver?

Not illegal but it could be considered as being 'user-hostile'.

Suppose I'm at a tricky part in a game and I'm just about to complete a particularly difficult level...and your Dialog appears and blocks my game-play until I click 'OK'? How long do you think it will be before your app is un-installed from my device? Pretty damn quick. What you're suggesting sounds like a system modal dialog which effectively amounts to hijacking the device.

It's OK to use modal dialogs within your own app, i.e., when a user is actually using one of your Activities but the acceptable approach at other times is to use Notifications.

Having said all that, however, if you're determined to go with this approach I'd suggest you use an Activity with the Dialog theme. Rather than using the direct approach to creating something like an AlertDialog, simply trigger the Activity with an Intent.

Comment: of course! DUH! sometimes you get so wrapped up in the details that you forget how things really look.  Your concern is totally valid, regarding the inconveniencing of the user, however, in this case, this is a custom app that will be running on custom devices specifically used for a custom purpose... so any game playing is... well... let's just say the client would be annoyed that someone would be playing games on their nickel  :)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: I wondered if it might be a corporate app at which point it's perhaps more acceptable but if the device needs to be used for other purposes then obviously taking that into consideration is important. By the way, I personally don't play games on my device. Useful example though. :D